# Pandas method for copying specific items from a column

Tags: python, pandas

The "released" column in my df has dates like "June 20, 1980 (United States).
The "year" column in the same df has only years like "1980".

But some of the rows have years in the "year" column, which do not correspond to the years in the "released" column for the same row.

I used the code below to create a new "year" column:

```
df['yearcorrect'] = df['released'].astype(str).str[6:11]
df
```

This runs but does not return the year. It returns info like "198", "19" etc.

I hope the problem is clear enough.
kindly help.

Comment: I'd instead suggest to separate the year in a different way, by splitting the string for example

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment - split the string by whitespace and take the third item. Assuming that your data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'released': ['June 20, 1980 (United States)','May 18, 1970 (Sweden)']})
df['year'] = df['released'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[2])
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I got this error;

----> 3 df['yearcorrect'] = df['released'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split()[2])
      4 df

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: How does the other strings in the column look like? It might be because the string does not always look like the one, that you wrote in the question. Maybe try to run it without the ```[2]```?

Comment: The other strings looks exactly like the one in the question. I have tried running it without the [2] but it returned an error.

Comment: Actually, you should not need the ```.astype(str)``` as I guess that your column is already a string? I assume that something in your data looks different, but it is difficult for me to know. Try to look at this example: 
```df = pd.DataFrame({'released': ['June 20, 1980 (United States)','May 18, 1970 (Sweden)']})
df['year'] = df['released'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[2])
df```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "released" column has always the same structure, you can use:

```
import re

df['yearcorrect'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^0-9]', "", x.released.split(",")[1]), axis = 1)
```

which extracts only the numeric characters in the part of the string after the comma.

Comment: <ipython-input-42-fb44b41738fb> in <lambda>(x)
      3 import re
      4 
----> 5 df['yearcorrect'] = df.apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^0-9]', "", x.released.split(",")[1]), axis = 1)

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I don't know exactly how your data looks like, but this can happen if, for example, some of the cells in your "released" column do not contain a comma. That is why I wrote "assuming that your "released" column has always the same structure"